# Equivalent statements for $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu).$

Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

1. For all $p,q \in [1,\infty[,p \neq q,,L^p_{\mathbb{R}}(\mu) \neq L^q_{\mathbb{R}}(\mu).$
2. There exists a sequence $(E_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements in $\mathcal{A},$ pairwise disjoint, such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N},0<\mu(E_k)<\infty.$

For 1. $\implies$ 2. it's sufficient to note that if $f \in L^1 \setminus L^2,$ then $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}(2^{-k-1}\mu(\left\{2^{-k-1} \leq |f| <2^{-k}\right\})+2^{k}\mu(\left\{2^k \leq |f|<2^{k+1}\right\}))<\infty$ and $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}(2^{-2(k+1))}\mu(\left\{2^{-k-1} \leq |f| <2^{-k}\right\})+2^{2k}\mu(\left\{2^k \leq |f|<2^{k+1}\right\}))=\infty.$

Therefore for every $k \in \mathbb{N}, \mu(\{2^{-k-1} \leq |f| <2^{-k}\} \cup)\{2^{k} \leq |f| <2^{k+1}\}<+\infty.$ Define $\phi(0):=\inf\{k \in \mathbb{N},\mu(\{2^{-k-1} \leq |f| <2^{-k}\} \cup\{2^{k} \leq |f| <2^{k+1}\})>0\}$ and for every $n \in \mathbb{N},\phi(n+1)=\inf\{k \geq \phi(n)+1,\mu(\{2^{-k-1} \leq |f| <2^{-k}\} \cup\{2^{k} \leq |f| <2^{k+1}\})>0\},E_n:=\{2^{-\phi(n)-1} \leq |f| <2^{-\phi(n)}\} \cup\{2^{\phi(n)} \leq |f| <2^{\phi(n)+1}\}.$

Clearly $(E_k)_k$ verifies 2.

How to prove 2. $\implies $ 1. ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A measure space which satisfying $\inf\{\mu(E): E\in M \text{ such that } \mu(E)&gt;0\}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822660/a-measure-space-which-satisfying-inf-mue-e-in-m-text-such-that-mue)

Comment: No, there is a clear difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\{E_k\}$ allows you to consider functions of the form
$$
f=\sum_k\alpha_k\,\frac1{\mu(E_k)^{1/p}}\,1_{E_k}, 
$$
where you get
$$
\|f\|_p=\Big(\sum_k|\alpha_k|^p\Big)^{1/p}
$$
Now you can choose the coefficients so that for $p>q$, $f\in L^p\setminus L^q$.